# Running shell under gulp : evitate the antislash (\) character exlusion effect

Tags: javascript, shell, gulp

I'm running shell tasks under Gulp

By the manner i'm used to write shell syntax with javascript.

Among my tasks i wanna execute a "zip" tas with excluding some files ; my origin shell command is this :

```
'zip -9 -r project.zip ./* -x *.svn* -x custom/\*
```

As you can see i'm excluding the whole "custom" repo.

My gulp task is that one :

```
gulp.task('package-IC', shell.task([
  'zip -9 -r project.zip ./* -x *.svn* -x custom/\*
]));
```

But the problem that with javascript the succession of the characheters `\*` 
eliminates the `*` from the command .

How can i keep the anti-slash **\** without loosing the character just after it ?

**Suggestions ??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backslashes in JavaScript strings have special meaning, since they can be used for escape sequences. You need to escape the backslash character itself:

```
'zip -9 -r project.zip ./* -x *.svn* -x custom/\\*'
```

Also your gulp example code is missing the closing single quote.